# Sum over subsequences of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Looking for some references or hints on the following:

Suppose we have a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $\alpha=\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ and we define the sum
$$
S_\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{a_k^2}.
$$
Clearly when $\alpha$ has a finite number of terms, i.e. when $n<\infty$, then $S_\alpha$ is rational. And when $\alpha=\mathbb{N}$ we have $S_\alpha=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which is irrational.

I am interested in finding infinite sequences for which $S_\alpha$ is rational, if there are any. Does anyone know of a good source where this idea might be discussed?

Comment: $a_k=2^k$.......

Comment: [Hurwitz's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)) suggests there cannot be very many such infinite sequences.

Comment: Hurwitz's theorem has hardly anything to do with this.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thank you. I thought of the geometric series shortly after I posted this, but I wonder if there any arithmetic sequences that would produce a rational sum.

Comment: @EricTowers I agree with Ivan. I don’t see how Hurwitz’s Theorem says anything about this. If you have some time, could you elaborate?